# Catkin make fails after adding gtest

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a package, that contains custom messages and services. This package was building well and everything was ok. But recently I added `gtest` to my package and faced with some interesting issue. If I build my package with:

```
catkin_make my_pkg_name
```

It builds ok, gtest also works after

```
catkin_make run_test_my_pkg_name_gtest
```

But if I try `catkin_make` without any arguments it fails with this error:

```
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_pkg_name/include/my_pkg_name/map_handler.h:8:10:

fatal error: custom_msgs/Map.h: no such file or directory

include "custom_msgs/Map.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated
```

where Map.h is a definition of my custom service. If I switch to version of my package without gtest `catkin_make` works again.

I suppose that problem connects with gtest module which doesn't know something about my custom messages and services at the building time. But strange that it works for building only one package (not whole catkin directory).

Any ideas on this case? I would appreciate practical advise how to solve this problem and theoretical explanations about catkin_make features.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376154/catkin-make-fails-after-adding-gtest/) by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-15**:
Do you have your non-test code and your test code in different directories? The different directories might make some difference.
In this case, you may be able to solve it by writing `include_directories`.

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-04-16**:
Yes, my test code is in folder called test. If I move it to the src folder error doesn't disappear. Also I tried to add test folder in `include_directories` but result was the same.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-17**:
You can get the build details by enabling `VERBOSE=1`.
Can you please try

```
catkin_make my_pkg_name VERBOSE=1
```

and

```
catkin_make run_test_my_pkg_name_gtest VERBOSE=1
```

There should be some difference.

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-04-19**:
Yes, results of above commands execution are difference. There are a lot of some different message and I actually don't understand what I should do with this information. As I can see the `catkin_make run_test_my_pkg_name_gtest VERBOSE=1` enters into my_package_name directory only, when `catkin_make my_pkg_name VERBOSE=1` enters into custom_msgs directory which contains definitions of my custom messages. Does this information tell you anything?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-19**:
If you share the messages and CMakeLists.txt with us, we may be able to notice something.

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-04-19**:
OK, There is my [CMakeLists.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pKErCMmzgf-AoOf4UXE3ncc7JfhoykDe/view?usp=sharing), this is [output of `catkin_make my_pkg_name VERBOSE=1`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_G23JJZ6yqFzqT26IBIvJJtMp2XmFT7/view?usp=sharing) and this is [output of `catkin_make run_test_my_pkg_name_gtest VERBOSE=1`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aSb3_P2SVGTY8TNtyC-vuVVbWihfIm5C/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixing `CMakeLists.txt` seems to work.

`test/main_test.cpp` defines a dependency that requires `custom_msgs`.

```
## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/main_test.cpp)
  add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) # added
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PROJECT_NAME}_test)
endif()
```

Reference: https://answers.ros.org/question/286311/when-is-catkin_exported_targets-needed/

### Update

I found something else.

```
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_test ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}) # added
```

The following may also be relevant.

```
catkin_package(
# INCLUDE_DIRS include
# LIBRARIES Software_maps_and_roots
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs # update
   r2_msgs # added
   sensor_msgs # added
   cv_bridge # added
# DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-04-20**:
I tried to add this line to my `CMakeLists.txt`, but I have the same error.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-20**:
I re-read `CMakeLists.txt` and updated it.

Not an answer, but something I was wondering. `add_message_files`, `generate_messages` were commented. Are you building the custom messages in a separate `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-04-21**:
Yes, I have separate ros-package with all my custom messages. I added to my CMakeLists.txt only this line:

```
add_dependencies (${PROJECT_NAME}_test ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

and everything works! I assume that is because my dependency 'test' was know nothing about other packages (including package with my custom messages). Now it works, thank you!

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-21**:
Congratulations.